# After loading an image I am trying to run audio file

Tags: python, pygame

from https://github.com/OthmanAlkandri/game_using_pygame.gitusing  **Aduio_integration_aprroch2.py**
After loading the Image, I am trying to play audio files using the following commands and library.

```
from pygame import mixer


"""" lad the mp3 files"""
"""" lad the mp3 files"""
r= open("/Users/okand/Documents/school/code/tiger.wav",)
s= open("/Users/okand/Documents/school/code/tiger1.wav",)


right = pygame.mixer.Sound(r)
tiger1 = pygame.mixer.Sound(s)



pygame.mixer.Sound.play(tiger1)      
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

The problem I did not resolve is that I could not integrate the audio files so my code should play different audio files when different pics are being displayed, but they are,  not the audio files are being overlapped. This is my flowchart I hope it will support the explanation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGUIY.png)

Answer (score -1):

Don’t have enough rep to comment, sos I must says this as an answer. If you used the from pygame import mixer, then you don’t need to use pygame.mixer...

That could be your problem...

Comment: If you don't have enough [reputation to comment](/help/privileges), the correct course of action is to contribute to other posts that do not require commenting. If you answer other well-asked questions with well-written answers, it's quite easy to gain the required reputation quickly.